# How do you stream your screen via python and nodejs (both with socket.io) to a webpage

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, socket.io, streaming

I'm working on a website that turns my ipad into a drawing tablet for my laptop.

Most of the program is done, but I don't know how I'm gonna share my screen with my ipad.

Does one of you guys know how to do that?
If so then please let me know how

for the website I'm using nodejs & socket.io (html, css and js) and for actually moving the mouse I'm using python (pynput, python-socketio)

Answer (score 0):

Well,
you can capture 24 screenshots a second with [PyAutoGUI](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/) and then send the data through a socket connection(see [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/156704/network-protocol-using-tcp-sending-images-through-sockets) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994937/send-image-using-socket-programming-python))...

But i don't see the reason to do so. If you want to use your ipad as a drawing tablet you also need to sync the input and the latency will be substantial.
You will be better off by just using teamviewer or some other remote control app. Those services are much better at handling latency and input.

Sorry, but it will save you a ton of work and pain.